# sklearn : get prediction along with score in Random Forest classifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am able to get individual prediction values for each row in `Random Forest` classifier.

Is there is any way to get prediction score for each row?

I am able to get the prediction  accuracy score for the whole data. But I need it separately for each row.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by prediction score for a row? What was the calculated probability of selected class? Because I think that a row score can be either true or false - you can check if you hit on target for selected row by just comparing the test data with predicted ones.

Comment: Am I need to do it manually?@Konrad Lyda

Comment: Please explain with example what you want. What type of score will you calculate. For a single row, either the prediction from model will match the true label or not. Nothing else

Comment: How to find whether it is true or false? @Vivek Kumar

Comment: clf = RandomForestClassifier()                         clf.fit(trainArr, trainRes[:,0])                                   clf.score(trainArr, trainRes[:,0]) - here i get the accuracy score.   result = clf.predict(testArr) . Here the result will give the prediction label. In addition to that I want to know whether the predicted value is true or false. As of now I manually compare the values and find it. Is there anyway to do it automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done easily by just comparing the arrays. No need to do it row by row.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

predictions = clf.predict(X)
comparison = (pred==y)

print(comparison)
Output: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
   False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
    True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True])
```

The False denotes that the prediction was wrong in that case.

Comment: Thanks.Able to view the results in the above format@Vivek Kumar